# Magento2.4 translation language

Tags: magento2, language, module-development

app/code/Mage/New
I have created a module, a view code file, and a translation language package. But my page doesn't work.
code:
view file

```
app/code/Mage/New/view/frontent/templates/a.phtml:

 <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl() ?>">
                       <button><?= __('Buy Now') ?></button>
                   </a>
```

Bellow is a language file:

```
app/code/Mage/New/i18n/zh_Hant_TW.csv

"Buy Now",立即購買,module,Mage_New
"Buy Now",立即購買,module,Mage_New
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial for the same. I hope this will work for you.

https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-create-and-use-language-package-component-in-magento-2/

Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: Thanks ,very good

Comment: Welcome. Please vote if solution worked for you